# Problemas e dúvidas com envio de dados Ajax e form PhP

Tags: php, ajax

Olá. Preciso salvar umas informações do formulário html em php mas sem recarregar a página. Procurei vários tutoriais e video aula de ajax mas estou fazendo algo muito errado ou realmente não entendi nada de como funciona o ajax.
Meu html:

```
<form method='post' id="form">
Nome: <input name="nome" id="nome" type="text"/>
<input type="hidden" name="acao" />
<input type="submit" value="Enva" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#form").serialize,
            url: 'teste.php',
            success:function(data) {
                // deu certo?
            }
    }); 
});
});
```

Arquivo php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["acao"])){
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    var_dump($nome);
}
```

Por que não envia nada no php? o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Aparece algum erro no console do navegador?

Comment: Tens de invocar esse serialize com `()`... ou seja: `$("#form").serialize()`

Comment: Seu input hidden 'acao' não tem nenhum valor definido e não vi nenhum lugar que você sete algum valor, defina um antes do envio

Answer (score 0):

Tente esta solução:

Na parte do HTML:

```
<input name="nome" id="campo_nome" type="text"/>
<input type="hidden" name="acao" id="campo_acao" />
<button id="btn_enviar" type="button"></button>
```

Na parte do JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY:

```
$('#btn_enviar').on('click', function(){
{
    var campo_acao = $('#campo_acao').val();
    var campo_nome = $('#campo_nome').val();

    // Caso seja via texto:
    //var dados = 'acao=' + campo_acao + '&nome=' + campo_nome;

   // Caso seja via JSON
    var dados = {
        acao : campo_acao,
        nome : campo_nome
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'nomeEnderecoArquivoAjax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dados,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){  
            alert('dados enviados!');
        }
    });
}
```

Arquivo PHP:

```
// Veja o que está chegando no arquivo PHP
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: Primeiro, atente-se ao fato levantado nos comentários: o campo `hidden` não possui um valor definido. Segundo, o que você quer dizer com "caso seja via JSON"?

Comment: if(isset($_POST["acao"])) -> me parece que quando o formulário for carregado, poderá haver um valor definido e este é o momento do teste que ele faz, mas ao que entendi a dificuldade seria em passar dados para a página PHP via Ajax. "caso seja via JSON"? -> Opcional a forma de passar os dados para a pagina PHP, seja via JSON ou via texto normal, isso que quis dizer.